# How to parse JSON/REST data from server using Perl

Tags: json, perl, rest

Im trying to parse out JSON output from the server using Perl. The connection and downloading of the REST data is ok, I just need help parsing the returned data. Here is the snippet for my code:

```
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($SERVER_ADDR);
if ($response->{success})
{
    my $html = $response->{content};
    @LINES = split /\n/, $html;
    chomp(@LINES);
    print("Lines: '@LINES'\n"); # ZZZ
    my $decoded_json = decode_json( $html );
    print Dumper $decoded_json;
}
else
{
    print "Failed: $response->{status} $response->{reasons}";
}
```

And here is the results:

```
Lines: '{"players":[{"currentlyOnline":false,"timePlayed":160317,"name":"MarisaG","lastPlayed":1474208741470}]}'
$VAR1 = {
      'players' => [
                     {
                       'currentlyOnline' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
                       'timePlayed' => 160317,
                       'lastPlayed' => '1474208741470',
                       'name' => 'MarisaG'
                     }
                   ]
    };
```

There will be multiple entries under the "players" for each player logged in right now. Any tips?

Comment: You've already parsed json with `decode_json()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. You have successfully parsed the JSON by by calling `decode_json()`. You now have a data structure in `$decoded_json`. Your call to `Dumper()` shows the structure of that data. It's a hash reference with a single key, `players`. The value associated with that key is an array reference. Each element in the referenced array is another hash.

So, for example, you could print all of the players' names with code like this.

```
foreach (@{ $decoded_json->{players} }) {
  say $_->{name};
}
```

Comment: What are your thoughts regarding postfix `->@*` dereferencing?

Comment: @Сухой27 that it's more of a pain than it's worth while it requires `use feature` and `no experimental` pragmas.  You could adopt it for an entire code base and have that in the standard init code you always use, but it doesn't belong in short examples.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I quite like postfix dereferencing. But I won't be using it in answers on SO for some time, as most people won't be using versions of Perl that support it.

Comment: @ysth, Neither are needed in 5.24+ (and you meant `no warnings ...`, not `no experimental ...`)